# Using an HTML slider to change the link of a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a very basic slider

```js
var slider = document.getElementById("myRange");
var output = document.getElementById("demo");
output.innerHTML = slider.value; // Display the default slider value

// Update the current slider value (each time you drag the slider handle)
slider.oninput = function() {
    output.innerHTML = this.value;
}
```

```css
.slider {
      -webkit-appearance: none;  /* Override default CSS styles */
      appearance: none;
      width: 100%; /* Full-width */
      height: 25px; /* Specified height */
      background: #ffffff; /* Grey background */
      outline: none; /* Remove outline */
      opacity: 0.7; /* Set transparency (for mouse-over effects on hover) */
      -webkit-transition: .2s; /* 0.2 seconds transition on hover */
      transition: opacity .2s;
  }

  /* Mouse-over effects */
  .slider:hover {
      opacity: 1; /* Fully shown on mouse-over */
  }

  /* The slider handle (use webkit (Chrome, Opera, Safari, Edge) and moz (Firefox) to override default look) */ 
  .slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
      -webkit-appearance: none; /* Override default look */
      appearance: none;
      width: 25px; /* Set a specific slider handle width */
      height: 25px; /* Slider handle height */
      background: #4CAF50; /* Green background */
      cursor: pointer; /* Cursor on hover */
  }

  .slider::-moz-range-thumb {
      width: 25px; /* Set a specific slider handle width */
      height: 25px; /* Slider handle height */
      background: #4CAF50; /* Green background */
      cursor: pointer; /* Cursor on hover */
  }
```

```html
<div id="slidecontainer">
  <input type="range" min="500" max="2500" value="500" step="100" class="slider" id="myRange">
</div>

<a href="#" class ="button style3">Go</a>
```

I am trying to make this slider change a link in a button, but I have no idea how to even go about it. I am not very good at javascript, but if you give me ideas Im sure I can manage. My end goal is to have this slider change  a link within a button based on the position of the slider.

Answer (score 2):

The simpliest idea come to my mind is, defining for example

```
var a100 = "www.cr8code.co";
var a200 = "www.google.com";
```

And then getting the value of the slider like;

```
$('.slider').change(function(){
var y = $('.slider').val();
y = 'a'+y;
$('button').attr('href',eval(y));
});
```

It will ge the value of the slider for exmaple if value is 100 then link will be "cr8code.co" if value 200 link will be "google.com"
Btw, I suppose the button is `<a>` tag other wise if it is `<button>` the logic is same but you gonna change the code.

Comment: I know this sounds dumb, but how do I implement this into my button? I have updated the post to include the code for my button. Thanks!

Comment: I have done a mistake it should be eval() instead of window[]. Chcek the link below to see the demo http://cr8code.co/editor.php?workid=ef666e8eac61a617d31bc79d09c563a5

Comment: How do I tie my button to the js code. The code is in different documents. Do i just change the part where it is $(document).ready(function(){ to my linked html file?

Comment: No, just copy the javascript code, then create a script tag into your html page's head and paste the js code inside the script tag. Also do you have jquery included in your web page?

Comment: I do. the script tag I created was <script type="text/javascript>"code here"</script> and when I click the "go" button all that happens is my page goes back to the top of the page.

Comment: Make sure your button's href is '#' at first. When you slide it to 600 at my code it will change to the defined link.

Comment: And make sure you dont have any other class with 'button' if you do change the clasa of your button to somethinf unique and change it from js code to the same as well. If you have other buttons with same class, probably it is submiting a form thats why it freshes the page.

Comment: Here is the code I have (The js in the bottom is in another page, and it displays the number similar to your "a500, a600, etc" without the a in front) http://www.cr8code.co/editor.php?workid=405ed72b4bdf6ff6fd7eb40bf009d2e5

Comment: When im sliding it to 600 and click go it is working.

Comment: On my site, when I click it, it still just goes to the top of the screen. It isn't refreshing either, just going to the top. no idea why.

Comment: Share me the link of your website.